# Bootstrap 4 input doesn't stop at padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm making a simple form with this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="width:100%">
        <h1>
            ConfigTool Web Interface
        </h1>
        <p>
            Edit the config variables here and click save.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control col-10" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

You can see that the input does not align with the jumbotron, and that is because the input doesn't stop at the padding:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't give form input elements a `col-` class. You should put the input inside of a div that has the `col-` class. Now you're just giving padding to the input element, which you can see in element in as the green area.

Comment: Use [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row). You should not put `col-` on inputs directly but surround it with a div that has `col-` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="width:100%">
        <h1>
            ConfigTool Web Interface
        </h1>
        <p>
            Edit the config variables here and click save.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <label>Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should use `col-*` inside a div tag

Comment: You only need the `col-[0-12]` class if they're equal on all sizes (Bootstrap 4).

Answer (score 0):

Column classes should be given to the elements surrounding the input controls (and labels). The Bootstrap grid system works best as follows:
`div.container` > `div.row` > `div.col-*` > `content`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="width:100%">
        <h1>
            ConfigTool Web Interface
        </h1>
        <p>
            Edit the config variables here and click save.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Name:</label>

        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added Bootstrap's predefined grid classes in input element. So, Grid classes padding apply in input element. You will need to create grid classes with separate div element. then put input element inside this div element.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="width:100%">
        <h1>
            ConfigTool Web Interface
        </h1>
        <p>
            Edit the config variables here and click save.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also, Please check this official bootstrap [Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#horizontal-form)

Comment: Please explain your answer, that way, the person asking the question can actually understand why this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parent element for the form-group. Try this -

```
 <div class="form-horizontal" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove the "row" class from the form-group. the row class basically remove the padding from the div element.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-2">Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control col-10" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the actual problem, which is that you need to wrap the input controls with actual `div`s that have a column class